# change url format in yii2 application

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii2, url-routing

As you know in MVC.NET we have areas which give ability of separating admin part with user part. In application folder indexing is like below:

```
/Areas
    /Admin
        /Controllers
        /Models
        /Views
/Controllers
/Models
/Views
```

Above style shows that we have different folders for controllers, Models and Views .
Url for parts which are sub folder of an area are like this
`domain.pre/area/controller/action`
and url for parts which are not sub folder of an area are like this `domain.pre/controller/action`
know in yii2 we do not have areas. My question is that If we have two controller like `A` and `B` can we define a different url for one of them?
For example route of `A` controller be like this `domain.pre/A/index` and route of `B` controller be like this `domain.pre/admin/B/index`

Thank you for your time and response

**Edit**

I have 4 controller named `Word`, `Panel`, `Regex` and `Language` if I want to access to the index action of each controller I should follow this rule:

```
mysite/panel/index
mysite/word/index
mysite/regex/index
mysite/language/index
```

know i want change urls to these formats:

```
mysite/panel/index
mysite/admin/word/index
mysite/admin/regex/index
mysite/admin/language/index
```

Comment: modules? you can read about modules [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)..

Comment: yes you can call both differently . but what you want to do i don't understand  exactly.

Comment: I am not sure exactly. I follow the guide but when I enter url I face with an 404 error @Coderanonymous

Comment: I want to add a prefix to controller `B` url @jilesh

Comment: can you give me any proper example or put your code here using edit post ?

Comment: if you want to do it in different controller please create different controller using gii module or custom and create controller A and controller B in controllers and create index() action in both controller you will access it differntly

Comment: @jilesh please check the edit

Comment: i think there is two way first one you put your code in admin module or generate your crud using gii into admin module or second one you will define rewrite rule of url

Comment: Thank you for your help @jilesh . I have create a module but I can't access it from url. It faces me with a 404 error

Comment: i think you made some mistake other wise its not possible. please can you show me what url you got ?

Comment: Yes I have create an admin module and a default controller inside it. Then i want to use `mysite/admin/default/index` it faces me with 404

Comment: but what you got like i.e 404, 'Page not found' or anything else ?

Comment: yes. I tested for other controllers I got same error too. maybe something is going wrong  :|

Comment: please check your default controller extend to main controller and check public function actionIndex() is available in default controller ?

Comment: I checked it. It has the actionIndex. I don't know what is the problem. Should I configure `urlManager`?

Comment: i am not sure because i didn't see your code but check this url 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163778/yii2-url-not-found-shown-while-accessing-controller-action

hope it will helpful to you

Comment: @jilesh many thanks for you responses buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the url format that you want to achieve,

```
mysite/panel/index
mysite/admin/word/index
mysite/admin/regex/index
mysite/admin/language/index
```

You have to include UrlManager configuration like below.

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName'=>false
    ]
```

If you do not add this in your config file, you can only access your website's pages this way.

```
mysite/index.php?r=panel/index
mysite/index.php?r=admin/word/index
```